# Edge does not see button press on mouseleave / mouseenter

Tags: javascript, dom-events, microsoft-edge

Left mouse button was pressed or not - `Edge` always shows `.buttons` and `.button` as **0**. `.which` is always **1**.
Other browsers work fine. Other events like `click` work fine in `Edge` too. Trouble is with `mouseleave` and `mouseenter`.

So how can I detect in `Edge` on `mouseleave` event if left mouse button was pressed or not?

[image]

**P.S.** I can solve it with ugly flag like "`isClicked`" and update it in all related events like `mousedown`, `mouseup`. But it is ugly and bug prone.

Comment: I tested and reproduced the issue in Microsoft Edge. The workaround I can find now is just tracking the button status by yourself. I think the behavior is by-design in Microsoft Edge. We'll report the issue to Microsoft Edge Team. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The #1 best answer: Tell your users that you do not support MS Edge.

If that is not an option, then you'll need to track the mouse button status yourself, like

```
var leftPressed;

function init() {
  document.body.addEventListener("mousedown mouseup") {
    //update leftPressed
  }
}
```

Comment: I'd love to say so ). But it is not my decision to support Edge. At least I'm happy that don't support IE10-

Comment: I end up tracking button state by additional flag as don't see other workarounds.